# Can I get a Nokia Lumia Icon outside the US?

Tags: lumia

I am from Algeria, I saw the new Nokia Lumia Icon smartphone, and I like it and want to own one. But I don't know if this is possible since its exclusively available from Verzion. They say its unlocked but I'm not sure if it will work with a different network here in Algeria. So can you tell me what options do I have? can I buy it and get it to work with our networks here? answers please, I cannot wait to get that incredible phone.

Comment: Have you considered waiting for the Lumia 930 instead? It's basically the same phone, except comes with Windows Phone 8.1 and is (or will be) available globally.

Comment: @Indrek When it will be released?

Comment: Supposedly in June 2014, but availability in your country might vary. You can check with your local wireless carriers or Nokia representative to see if they have a more specific timeline for availability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check at the online stores like EBAY/Amazon if they provide it over there, and be sure to check if its unlocked or not. Else you need to pay more to get it unlocked. But all this doesn't provide you the surety that it will work with your local network operator.

Best option is to wait for Lumia 930

Comment: Thank you @Apoorv, I think its better to wait for the 930.